# Failed to install cabal-install (v. 1.22.0.0)

Tags: haskell, cabal-install

**Failed to install cabal-install (v. 1.22.0.0) in Windows Command Prompt and in Cygwin64 Terminal.**

As usual in Windows, cabal fails to update cabal-install. I use Haskell Platform 2014.2.0.0.

Actual cabal version:

```
$ cabal -V
cabal-install version 1.20.0.4
using version 1.20.0.2 of the Cabal library
```

**Windows Command Prompt**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Note: there is a new version of cabal-install available.
To upgrade, run: cabal install cabal-install

C:\Windows\system32>cabal install cabal-install
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring cabal-install-1.22.0.0...
Building cabal-install-1.22.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'cabal' for cabal-install-1.22.0.0...
[ 1 of 77] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.Modular.Version ( Distributi
on\Client\Dependency\Modular\Version.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution
\Client\Dependency\Modular\Version.o )
[ 2 of 77] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.Modular.PSQ ( Distribution\C
lient\Dependency\Modular\PSQ.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\
Dependency\Modular\PSQ.o )
...
...
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x44d6): undefined reference to `shutdow
nWinSock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x4c8e): undefined reference to `shutdow
nWinSock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x4ceb): undefined reference to `initWin
Sock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x4e36): undefined reference to `shutdow
nWinSock'
c:/program files/haskell platform/2014.2.0.0/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-min
gw32/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\R
oaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/libHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o
): bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data'
c:/program files/haskell platform/2014.2.0.0/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-min
gw32/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid
 operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Failed to install cabal-install-1.22.0.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cabal-install-1.22.0.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

**From Cygwin64  Terminal:**

```
Alberto@Alberto-PC ~
$ cabal install cabal-install
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring cabal-install-1.22.0.0...
Building cabal-install-1.22.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'cabal' for cabal-install-1.22.0.0...
[ 1 of 77] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.Modular.Version ( Distribution\Client\Dependency\Modular\Version.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Dependency\Modular\Version.o )
[ 2 of 77] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.Modular.PSQ ( Distribution\Client\Dependency\Modular\PSQ.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Dependency\Modular\PSQ.o )
[ 3 of 77] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.Modular.Package ( Distribution\Client\Dependency\Modular\Package.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Dependency\Modular\Package.o )
...
...
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/libHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x4ceb): undefined reference to `initWinSock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/libHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x4e36): undefined reference to `shutdownWinSock'
c:/program files/haskell platform/2014.2.0.0/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/libHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o): bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data'
c:/program files/haskell platform/2014.2.0.0/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Failed to install cabal-install-1.22.0.0
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
cabal-install-1.22.0.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of network or HTTP installed?

Comment: 1. Remove your haskell folders from `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)` and `%AppData%/cabal`.

2. Reinstall haskell and cabal, from MinGW with admin privileges.

3. Let us know how that advanced....

Comment: @Amon 1) Do I need to uninstall the platform Haskell or manually delete the two directories of Haskell? 2) Simply delete the directory C: \ Users \ Alberto \ AppData \ Roaming? 3) Do I need to reinstall the Haskell  Platform from Cygwin64 Terminal or install separately Haskell and Cabal?

Comment: @user2407038: I do not know how to test it.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this problem had to do with installing `network` on Windows. New versions of the Haskell Platform, as well as stack all resolve this. Also, for installation of `cabal-install` in particular, binaries are provided on the cabal website.